# Do I need to take bath if my baby boy urinated on me?

Tags: taharah, ghusl, najis, baby

My baby boy is 6 months old. He eats baby food in-addition to breast Milk.If my baby passed urine on my body,do I need to bath or can I just wash the wet area so that my Salah will get accepted.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Your question lacks information, but I could clearly exclude the necessity of ghusl. While the necessity of wudu' depends on the sex of the baby, the food it eats and the maddhab. Urine in general might be najis, but one doesn't need to perform purification to regain tahrah. While is necessary  to remove the najassa (if any) in first place. [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33628/would-touching-the-private-parts-of-our-kids-also-invalid-our-wudu) is somewhat relevant.

Comment: What is Ghusl..? and what is Tahrah..?

Comment: Ghusl means washing the entire body. Tahrah is often translated as purity. It means being clean from anything that is regarded as najis (impure, impurity is referred to as najassa). Both are basic and standard terms. Bathing or taking a shower doesn't really describe ghusl.

Answer (score 2):

You need to thoroughly wash the contaminated area with water.

You do **not** need to perform ghusl or wudu just because of this.

The matters which invalidate wudu are mentioned [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11103). While ghusl is required when one of the following occurs:

- Secretion of sexual fluids from the private part
- Menstruation and post-natal bleeding
- Entering of the private parts into one another
- Death
- Converstion to Islam

There is an opinion in some madhabs where the urine of a male baby can just be sprinked over with water rather than properly washed, however this is applicable when he does not eat food.

---

**Reference:**

> touching najaasah does not invalidate wudoo’
>
> <sup>— [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/82517/) also see [here](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/13665) [here](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/12801/)</sup>

Comment: Id Ghusl means bathing..?

Comment: @Anees Yes ghusl is bathing, it involves washing the entire body with water. The requirements of it are mentioned in various answers on this site and elsewhere please google etc.

Comment: @UmH so what about old parents because one has to take care them like babies?

Comment: @Anonymous You can read the answer.

Comment: @UmH yeah I read the answer but it says when the baby doesn't eat food

Comment: That part has nothing to do with ghusl and wudu, it is about  washing the area soiled by urine. And it obviously is irrelevant to old parents since it only applies to a male child who is so young as to not eat solid food.

Comment: @UmH sorry for bothering you, if I have to take care of my old parents and in cleaning them their urine touched my clothes at many places and my body ,and I don't know where the urine touched my clothes, so what should I do ,how much area should I wash ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to make wudoo' if the urine gets onto your body (not only clothes), it doesn't matter if the urine is from a baby or someone else or yourself since it would be an impurity (najaasah). If it is only on your clothes, then you can clean the area with water and make wudoo' just in case. Be aware that this is just my interpretation/opinion, Allah knows best. For further information, please have a look here: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/12720/what-should-he-do-if-he-gets-urine-on-his-clothes

Comment: Your linked reference explicitly says that ghusl and wudu is not required, as opposed to your answer.