# Does cleaning a pet’s urine or excrement invalidate wudu?

Tags: salat, wudu

If you own a kitten, puppy, or other small animal (like a bird or hamster) as a pet, cleaning after its urine or excrement as it is learning to be potty-trained is a daily routine.

- Does cleaning after the pet invalidate wudu?
- Does it make any difference if you touch urine/excrement or not? Obviously you’d wash your hands afterwards.
- If the animal flatulates on you does that invalidate wudu?
- If it gets on your clothes I understand you have to either clean/change your clothes but is re-performing wudu necessary?
- What do those working in a farm or animal shelter where this work is done continuously do?

Please provide references.

Comment: Also see [touching an impurity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61567/).